# Access Road System (Formerly Path of the Rat)

Tags: geometry, optimization

There are six towns (see map below) that needs a road system to have access with each other. What is the minimum total length of 10ft. wide road pavement that can be constructed?

```
o---1mile---o---1mile---o

         1 mile             

o---1mile---o---1mile---o
```

Formerly (What is the shortest total length of path that the Rat can make to access all the pocket holes of a 1 x 2 snooker table?)

Comment: Yes @ArbitraryKangaroo, it is either trivial, or TSLF considers the holes to be circles (which the rat must touch), instead of points.

Comment: Lets consider hole center as point. Accessing the 6 center with shortest total length of path is what we are looking for.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo- around the perimeter is 6..not the shortest.

Comment: TSLF, the distance between any 2 centers is at least 1, and therefore the total length is at least 5, if you start from a center. There is something which is not explained well I guess.

Comment: Some pool table pockets has a rail or tunnel that goes down the front but that will not connect the centers..

Comment: I think this needs more detail - the shortest path is 5 units + minimum of {distance in a straight line to each pocket}. Are you asking for a path where if the rat retraces a portion it does not then count toward the total? Or are you expecting a non-Euclidian solution?

Comment: @JonathanAllan: It's extremely trivial that if you allow the non euclidean solution, the minimum is 1 unit + the rat to the nearest hole (Just make a torus, the top right, top left, bottom right, bottom left is then the same hole, and the middle right and left, another hole, so just two holes with one distance.)

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo and? As it stands the solution is even more trivial for most people; yet has not been accepted, which implies that the OP has probably not asked the question they mean, or not provided enough detail. The shortest path is the one where the rat does not do the moving :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan-imagine the pockets are 6 towns..what is the shortest length of road system that access all the towns?..or how to "connect the dots" (6 centers) with shortest total length of line segments?

Comment: @TSLF then update the question to correct it please.

Comment: No. Some understand it well.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo-Your first thought of perimeter path means you understand the question.

Comment: Path ..not to be mistaken as distance traveled by the rat.

Comment: Are we after the shortest path to access all the holes, or the set of paths (whose total length is the shortest) that allows access to any of the holes?  I know the question states that it is the former, but it seems like that is too simple (i.e. a length of 5 [plus the distance to the nearest hole - I didn't originally notice that the rat is shown on the table in the diagram]).

Comment: @YowE3K apparently it is the latter, and OP has explicitly declined to update the question to state that. I agree the question as worded strongly suggests it seeks a minimal trip length, not a minimal total aggregate length of all path segments.... and clearly, I'm not alone in thinking that.

Comment: I am VTC because puzzlers should not need to read through comments to dissect a question that needs to be reworded.

Comment: @TSLF, you problems are very nice, but if you don't start improving the presentation, all of them will be heavily voted down, which is a shame. At least let the more experienced users make changes, otherwise very few people will even understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @ Artur Kirkoryan - Is there a group of editors I can contact here?

Comment: You can use the chat rooms to discuss the problems, or just let other users make edits on them. @JonathanAllan above asked to improve the wording, but you declined him to do so.

Comment: if this question is asked right, it would be good question... but in this way, it is really bad one... you could ask "find the minimum total length of lines connecting all 6 points..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>Not a complete solution but a lead based on the interpretation
that the rat will wear a network of paths into the felt that allows the rat
to scurry from any hole to any other hole while staying on that network.</del>

The trail map of such a networked path with the shortest
total length of segments is called a...

> ...[Steiner tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem),
>  as seen on YouTube: [Steiner tree approximation 6 points](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAV1uCKYQSE)
>  
>  [image]
>
> <del>For anyone who wants to figure this out exactly...</del>
>
>  All 3-way intersections consist solely of 120° angles.

That image can be flipped and rotated so that
the 120° angles have more familiar alignments.
(Rotational symmetry is assumed.
 Lengths are even multiples for easier calculation.
 The lengths of the leftmost $\small 4a$ and $\small 2b$ segments
 are deduced from parallelism helped by the
 parallelogram with sides $\small 2a$ and $\small 2b$.)

> [image]

The diagram, with
$ \small\triangle \rm  ABC \cong \small\triangle \rm CDE $,
compels the following equalities.

$$\small\begin{align}
       4a+b & ~ = ~ \surd3c + \surd3b  \\[1ex]
     2a + c & ~ = ~ b + \surd3 b       \\[1ex]
(\surd 2)^2 & ~ = ~ (\surd 3c)^2 + \, (4a+b+\surd3b)^2
\end{align}$$

These shake out to:

$$\small\begin{align}
          a  & ~ = ~ \sqrt{ \scriptsize \frac{4-\surd3}{78} }  \\[1ex]
          b  & ~ = ~ \tfrac12 (1+\surd3) \, a             \\[1ex]
          c  & ~ = ~ \surd3 \, a
\end{align}$$

So the total length is:

$$\small\begin{align}
\textsf{length} & ~ = ~ 4a + 2b + 2c + 2a + 2b +2a + 2c + 4a + 2b  \\[1ex]
                & ~ = ~ (15 + 7\surd3) \sqrt{ \scriptsize
                                               \frac{4-\surd3}{78} } \\
                & ~ = ~ \sqrt{ 11+6\surd3}                            \\[1ex]
                & ~ = ~ 4.6251816...
\end{align}$$

This matches what
[2012rcampion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9718/2012rcampion)
reported (and probably derived with less behind-the-scenes algebra)
in a comment, along with interior coordinates.

> [image]

Comment: so what is the total length?

Comment: Using CAD the length can be determined easily..minimum=4.62  & jamal's 2nd solution is only 4.66 assuming Y angles are 120degrees

Comment: Okay I've formulated this on paper to get 4.6251816..., barring mistakes. I'd better post it while this answer is checked.  Cleaning it up and preparing a diagram.

Comment: With this configuration I get an exact answer of $\sqrt{11+6\sqrt{3}}$, with the intermediate points at $(9+\sqrt{3},6+5\sqrt{3})/39$ and $(69-\sqrt{3},33-5\sqrt{3})/78$ (with the other two symmetrically positioned).  And if you're curious, the paths are offset at an an angle of $\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{(41+6\sqrt{3})/52}\right)$.

Comment: I have the feeling that there are two questions here which are mixed up. There is a question of "what is the shortest path a rat should make while visiting each and every holes on the snooker table (start and end points are chosen arbitrarily)?"; and between "what is the shortest network joining all holes together?". I believe that the intentions of the OP was to ask the question answered here, nevertheless I am not at all convinced that this is the optimal solution *once a rat is actually travelling, and visiting each of the holes; thus turning around at several points*.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between demonstrating that such-and-such configuration has such-and-such length, whereas to argue that in fact *no shorter path is possible whatsoever*.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the nearest pocket then around the perimeter for the other 5 holes (1 unit between each hole) for a total of $5+x$ where $x<1$ is the distance from the mouse to the bottom right corner

Comment: Okay.. with that path he can go from hole to hole by traveling back and forth.. 5 is not short enough.

Comment: Should `5x` be `5 + x`?

Comment: @YowE3K it was 5.x (equivelent to 5+x) but it got edited on me.

Comment: Thinking about it in the morning it was a bad way of writing it just basically wanted to say it was between 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the shortest path

> [image]

if above is not the shortest path, how about this

> [image]

Comment: Nice improve. But not short enough

Comment: Jamal's route is shorter than 5

Comment: this might be the most efficient way to to join all the dots but not the shortest path by a long shot. Almost every lines will have to be crossed 2 times and the result will be way over 6. Or is that the catch? rather than total distance to be traversed by the rat, we are looking for an actual path length?

Comment: @stack reader- Yes. Shortest path length.(see Jamal's Answer)

Comment: @Rubio- Distance traveled by the Rat do not  add to the length of path when going back along the path to access holes

Comment: @TSLF I have add another picture, I think the second picture is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of anything better than to just follow the perimeter so i tried some outside the box thinking.

> I assume it's a pay to play table which locks the balls after one time.
>  I would say the best way is to jump in hole number one and then automatically slide through all the holes.
>  By stretching it a lot, one could say that the "path" that had to be taken to "access" all the holes was until the first hole.
>  And if that is not acceptable then it just comes back to the whole perimeter thing except that the rat can enjoy the ride.

Comment: The Snooker table dont have automatic slide down system.

Comment: more to the point - snooker tables have ball pockets, so there is no other sane path to follow from one pocket to another than traversing the tabletop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is allowed but...

> a human could suspend the rat slightly off the pool table, then the pool table could be maneuvered beneath the rat. this makes the path 0 (not including any vertical movement)